# Change gradient background on hover in MorphSVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to create morph animation with MorphSVG library.

I defined two gradients:

```
<linearGradient id="lgrad" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%" > 
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
  <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="lgrad-1" x1="12%" y1="100%" x2="88%" y2="0%" > 
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(153,218,255);stop-opacity:1" />
  <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,128,128);stop-opacity:1" />
</linearGradient>
```

I want to change these gradients on hover. How can I do this? My full program can be found on [codepen](https://codepen.io/eMeM/pen/VqvYqy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best answer you want...

But, this could be done in CSS/SCSS as an alternative by changing the fill gradient URL on :hover

```
#bean-2:hover {
  fill: url('#lgrad-1');
}
```

See the Pen [xmwOPe](https://codepen.io/Picksley/pen/xmwOPe/) by David Picksley ([@Picksley](https://codepen.io/Picksley)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

I would have done internal embed of code but MorphSVG throws up an error anywhere other than CodePen's library